# CentOS 7 mpath Install, Can't Find /dev/centos/root

Tags: linux, centos, installation, scsi, centos7

I am attempting to install CentOS 7 on an older SuperMicro H8QM8 motherboard (AIC-7902 SCSI controller, `aic7xxx` kernel module) with 3 attached drives.  The Adaptec SCSI bios recognizes the drives and they have each been low-level formatted via the SCSI bios.

On using the CentOS GUI install to configure the hard drive layout, the installer detects the SCSI devices as a single `mpath` device (is this normal?), however there a comment on the single `mpath` device `sda`, `sdb`, and `sdc`.  I seem to be able to successfully set up a partition table on a drive, but (at this point) I'm not sure exactly which drive I'm working on.

After the system reboots, I get an error about not finding `/dev/centos/root` and also not being able to find `/dev/by-uuid/blahblahblah` and get dropped into the dracut shell.  I am able to confirm that (at this point) the `aic7xxx`, `scsi_*`, and `dm_*` modules are loaded via a `kmod list` but don't see the various HD nodes that the boot sequence was looking for.  In `/dev` I see `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, and `/dev/sdc`, but no more specific partition nodes (i.e. `/dev/sda1`).  I don't seem to have access to `fdisk` at this point, so I can't see which SCSI drive has the partition table, however the log shows that "something" detected that `/dev/sda` has 3 partitions.

So then I reboot with the CentOS 7 CD in rescue mode, and the rescue boot successfully detects and mounts all my partitions under `/mnt/sysimage`.  At this point, I can see that the parititon table, file systems, and installed files all went to `/dev/sda` (`/dev/sda1` for `/boot`, `/dev/sda2` for `lvm`).

So there are a two sub-questions, but perhaps I don't quite know how the multipath works and it is just a single question:

- Why are the 3 drives displayed as a single mpath device in the installer?  In the installer, is there a way to address a single drive (e.g. `/dev/sda`) instead of the mpath device as a "whole"?
- Why can the installed system not find the parition table on `/dev/sda`?  What information can I use (perhaps from the dracut emergency prompt) to further debug?

Answer (score 1):

Passing the "nompath" option to the boot kernel (anaconda) solved my problem, as apparently the mpath recognition was a false positive.  Once I did that, everything proceeded normally, with individually addressable drives.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda_Boot_Options

Comment: Perhaps this is a dumb question but where did you add that parameter?